# Нужно ли обособлять конструкцию со "чтобы" в предложении с однородными сказуемыми?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Олег присел, чтобы поднять телефон(,) и отправился к выходу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Олег присел, чтобы поднять телефон, и отправился к выходу.**

Обособлять нужно, конечно. Конструкция со "чтобы" — это придаточное.

> Капустин обещал договориться с начальником школы, чтобы он увеличил
> Мересьеву число вылетов, и предложил Алексею самому составить себе
> программу тренировок (Пол.)

P.S. Олег, бедный, так в приседе и отправился к выходу? :)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134188/discussion-on-answer-by-nektoid--------).